# How to use string as ifstream variable name in C++

Tags: c++

I have one text file variables_n_paths.txt with these entries :

```
nsf_ttj    somepath1.txt
nsf_zz     somepath2.txt
hsf_ttw    somepath3.txt
hsf_wz     somepath4.txt
```

What I want is something like this (by using a loop):

```
ifstream nsf_ttj(somepath1.c_str());
ifstream nsf_zz(somepath2.c_str());
ifstream hsf_ttw(somepath3.c_str());
ifstream hsf_wz(somepath4.c_str());
```

What I do to achieve above is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  ifstream variable;
  string path;
  ifstream readfile("variables_n_paths.txt");
  while(true){
    if(readfile.eof()) break;
    readfile >> variable >> path; //it gives error here
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I am getting :

> error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream}’ and ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream}’)

I am wondering if this is even possible. Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You declared `variable` as an ifstream. You probably meant to make it a `string` instead.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But even if I declare it as a string, how can convert it to ifstream variablename?

Comment: You can't. Variable names are compile time constructs. They cannot be determined by runtime values. Why do you want to do this? What do you think it will help you achieve?

Comment: I thought so, thanks. I want to open those text files in a loop, to save the effort of doing it manually, and also wanted to have a reference to those further down the code. Any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create objects whose names are based on the input file's contents. This is not possible with pure c++ as the object names must be known at compile time.

One alternative is to read in the 'variable names' and filenames as strings, store them in a map and iterate through the map.

If you absolutely must create variable names from the file's contents, you will need to to use an external preprocessor that parses the text file and generates the corresponding c++ code containing the proper variable names.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that and will edit the post with answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to extract a string from a (file) stream. Your problem, as the error explains in more technical terms, is that `variable` is an `ifstream` and you cannot extract an `ifstream` from a stream. Simply change the type of `variable` to `std::string` and the extraction works.

Now that you have the name of the file in a string, you can stream the file:

```
std::string variable, path;
while(true) {
    readfile >> variable >> path;
    std::ifstream foo(path);
```

You can then go on and stream the contents of the file, and perhaps store them in a `std::map` using `variable` as key - or whatever you wish to do with your variables.